# Unable to proceed with Percona XtraDB Cluster installation from Source

Tags: mysql-5.7, percona-xtradb-cluster

I followed the official [guide](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/LATEST/install/compile.html#compile) to install PXC from source in my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. The process completed successfully and I got a `Percona-XtraDB-Cluster-5.7.22-rel22-29.26.1.Linux.x86_64.tar.gz` folder.

From this file, how can I install PXC in the machine?

**Note**: I tried this approach since installation `sudo apt-get install percona-xtradb-cluster-57` failed with the following error:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
>   percona-xtradb-cluster-57 :
>
> Depends: percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.7
>   (>= 5.7.22-29.26-1.xenial) but it is not going to be installed
>
> Depends: percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.7 (>= 5.7.22-29.26-1.xenial) but it is
>   not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
>   broken packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wasn't able to fix this.

Recreated Ubuntu VM and installation steps mentioned in the [guide](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/LATEST/install/apt.html#apt) worked without any problem.